# BeautifulSoup raise AttributeError when xml tag name contains capital letters

Tags: python, xml, google-app-engine, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get all the XML attributes for the tag `Name`.

Getting this error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'attrs'
```

when I executed the following code:

```
import BeautifulSoup as bs

xml = '''
<Product Code="1" HighPic="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/5f/Linksys48portswitch.jpg/220px-Linksys48portswitch.jpg" HighPicHeight="320" HighPicSize="37217" HighPicWidth="400" ID="35" Title="Demo Product">
<Category ID="23">
<Name ID="57" Value="Switches" langid="1"/>
</Category>
</Product>'''

doc = bs.BeautifulSoup(xml)
div = doc.find("Name")

for attr, val in div.attrs:
    print "%s:%s" % (attr, val)
```

I changed the tag `"Name"` to `"name"`, and then it works.

Why am I getting this error when the tag name contains capital letters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BeautifulSoup is a HTML-parsing library, primarily. It can handle XML too, but all tags are lowercased as per the HTML specification. Quoting the [BeautifulSoup documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#other-parser-problems):

> Because HTML tags and attributes are case-insensitive, all three HTML parsers convert tag and attribute names to lowercase. That is, the markup `<TAG></TAG>` is converted to `<tag></tag>`. If you want to preserve mixed-case or uppercase tags and attributes, you’ll need to parse the document as XML.

There *is* a [XML modus](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#parsing-xml) where tags are matches case-sensitively and are not lowercased, but this requires the `lxml` library to be installed. Because `lxml` is a C-extension library, this is not supported on the Google App Engine.

Use the [ElementTree API](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) instead:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
div = root.find('.//Name')

for attr, val in div.items():
     print "%s:%s" % (attr, val)
```

Comment: Thanks. How do i get the attribute for the `Product` tag ?

Comment: @Nijo: see the [`Element` interface](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#element-objects); use `root.get('Code')` for example.

Answer (score 0):

In BeautifulSoup 4, you can use

```
doc = bs.BeautifulSoup(xml, "xml")
div = doc.find("Name")
```

This should work.