# Grab XML tags by second attributes with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to pull NextBus data, specifically bus GPS real-time seen here: http://webservices.nextbus.com/service/publicXMLFeed?command=vehicleLocations&a=sf-muni&r=N&t=0

In it, there are tags that look like this:

```
<vehicle id="1534" routeTag="N" dirTag="N__OB1" lat="37.76931" lon="-122.43249" 
         secsSinceReport="99" predictable="true" heading="265" speedKmHr="37"/>
```

I'm learning python and have walked through to successfully pull a tag based on the attribute.  But I'm struggling for any attribute besides id.

So this works:

```
soup.findAll("vehicle", {"id":"1521"})[1]
```

But this returns an empty set

```
soup.findAll("vehicle", {"routeTag":"N"})
```

Any reason why?

Also, as I mentioned I'm brandnew to Python so if you have a favorite scraping tutorial feel free to leave a comment!

Comment: Unless you specifically told BeautifulSoup to parse as XML (only works with `lxml` installed) everything is *lowercased* because in HTML tags match case-insensitively.

Comment: possible duplicate of [BeautifulSoup raise AttributeError when xml tag name contains capital letters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21561977/beautifulsoup-raise-attributeerror-when-xml-tag-name-contains-capital-letters)

Answer (score 0):

To make it work, you should pass `xml` to `BeautifulSoup` constructor:

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://webservices.nextbus.com/service/publicXMLFeed?command=vehicleLocations&a=sf-muni&r=N&t=0'
soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(url), "xml")

print soup.find_all("vehicle", {"routeTag":"N"})
```

prints:

```
[
 <vehicle heading="-4" id="1431" lat="37.72223" lon="-122.44694" predictable="false" routeTag="N" secsSinceReport="65" speedKmHr="0"/>,
 ...
]
```

Or, thanks to @Martijn's comment, perform search in lower-case:

```
print soup.find_all("vehicle", {"routetag": "N"})
```

Also, note that you should use [BeautifulSoup4](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) and [find_all()](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all) method - the 3rd `BeautifulSoup` version is not maintained.